# Enabling browser scroll bars after window.open with scrollbars=no

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I have an existing link which opens up a webpage in a new window with scrollbars disabled as follows:

```
<a onclick='window.open("example.html", "name", "resizable=1,scrollbars=no,width=500,height=200");' href='#'>Click to pop up without scroll bars</a>
```

For the sake of argument, I cannot change this window.open() code. I need to enable scroll bars after the window has been opened.

This works in IE using the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    onload=function()
        {
    enableScrolling();
    }
    function enableScrolling()
    {
      document.body.scroll = "yes"; // IE 
    }
 </script>
```

However this does not work in FireFox or Chrome.

According to this page, the following code should work for FireFox and Chrome but it does not (perhaps this worked in earlier versions?)

```
      document.documentElement.style.overflow='scroll';
      document.body.style.overflow='scroll';
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to enable scroll bars in FireFox and Chrome after the window has been opened with scrollbars disabled?

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have resolved my problem due to your post. (At least for IE)

Comment: I don't think you can disable scrollbar in Chrome with that code, so you just need to find a fix for Firefox.

Comment: Try `<body scroll="false">` and javascript not good attribute scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Just like Nikunj Soni said, setting a `height` attribute to your `body` tag will help you solve the problem in every browser. What I will do differently is the following:

Instead of setting a fixed height, I would set `height:100%`, which enable you to open the popup also in different sizes than the original.

```
<body style="overflow:auto; height:100%;">
        The rest of your HTML code   
</body>
```

This is also not the best solution, but you are actually removing the restictions you get from the link.

Hope you find this answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you add js for IE I assume you can change the way displayed page works.
In that case I would try to put the contents of the opened window in div, and set its style to something like: height: 200px; overflow: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried with different browser, If you have fixed requirement about height, what you can do is wrap all the content of **example.html** in a specific div with the attached css like `overflow:auto;height:200px`. I will show you the whole code.

```
<body>
<div style="overflow:auto;height:200px;">
    Your HTML code       
</div>
</body>
```

put it into **example.html**. Height you can get from your code `window.open("example.html", "name", "resizable=1,scrollbars=no,width=500,height=200");`.

This is not the the actual solution but it will solve your problem in every browser.

Hope this help.